# Missing RelationalTypeMapping Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've manually set up my Entity Framework mappings using the fluent model builder, and everything works fine at the moment when I'm querying, but when trying to create an entity this is what I get:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: relationalTypeMapping

and here is the stacktrace:

> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypeMappedRelationalParameter..ctor(String invariantName, String name, RelationalTypeMapping relationalTypeMapping, Nullable`1 nullable)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalParameterBuilder.AddParameter(String invariantName, String name, IProperty property)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommandBuilderExtensions.AddParameter(IRelationalCommandBuilder commandBuilder, String invariantName, String name, IProperty property)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.CreateStoreCommand()
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>          at FastTrack.EntityFramework.Services.EntityFrameworkService`3.CreateAsync(TDto dto)

Here is my mapping code:

```
   builder.Entity(typeof(Page), b =>
            {
                b.HasOne(typeof(Site))
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("SiteId")
                    .IsRequired();
            });

            builder.Entity<Site>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Pages)
                .WithOne(x => x.Site)
                .HasForeignKey("SiteId")
                .IsRequired();
```

Here are the entities:

```
  public class Site
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public IList<Page> Pages { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
    }


   public class Page
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public IList<PageSelector> PageSelectors { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public Site Site { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Site")]
        public int SiteId { get; set; }
    }
```

What could possibly cause this to happen? The mappings seem to be correctly set up and everything works up until the post I want to insert something into the database.

Comment: Something is wrong with the mappings (`Page` shadow property "SiteId" seems to be mapped to two relationships). Can you post the `Page` and `Site` classes? And why do you use two (conflicting) mappings for one and the same relationship?

Comment: That is a good question, I thought I had to specify the relationship in the mapping for each entity.

Comment: Try removing the first one (which is incorrect anyway - `WithMany` does not specify `Pages` collection navigation property, which would let EF Core consider them two separate relationships).

Comment: Looking at the classes, everything follows EF Core conventions, so remove the `ForeignKey` attribute and the whole fluent configuration, and everything should be fine.

Comment: okay just tried removing it and it still doesn't work, if it helps, I'm trying to insert a Site with just the domain and the name set. There are no pages in the pages list.

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica can you try updating EF Core? And Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet?

Comment: its already up to date

Comment: The exception stack trace indicates unsupported property type, but it's unclear for which entity, property and type. Since the issue is not reproducing in a clean test environment, can you provide a full repro project (you would need that anyway in case you decide to go to EF Core issue tracker)?